# How to run n points FFT in R?

Tags: r, matlab, signal-processing

Suppose I have a length 100 vector x, in `Matlab`, I can run `fft(x,32)` to get a length 32 complex vector.

But how to do it in `R`?

`fft(x,32)` will not work and will still return a length 100 complex vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From MatLab documentation:

> Y = fft(X,n) returns the n-point DFT. If no value is specified, Y is
>   the same size as X.
>
> If X is a vector and the length of X is less than n, then X is padded with trailing zeros to length n.
>
> **If X is a vector and the length of X is greater than n, then X is truncated to length n.**
>   ...

To achieve same result in R:

```
fft(x[1:32])
```

Comment: But @HubertL, what happens if  `lenght(x)=1000` and `n=1024`, as in the matlab [doc](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html#buuutyt-10) ?

Comment: Hi @fina, you can pad X wilth zeros using `c(X, rep(0,n-length(X)))`