# Why n point FFT is equal to truncate the data, does it make the complexity of FFT O(1)?

Tags: time-complexity, fft

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38598542/how-to-run-n-points-fft-in-r) I learned n point FFT is `fft(x[1:N])`.

Why it is not `fft(x)[1:N]`?

If it is `fft(x[1:N])`, does it make the complexity to be O(1)? Instead of depending on signal length?

Answer (score 3):

An N-point FFT has complexity O(N log N). Indeed independent of original signal length.

`fft(x)[1:N]` does not yield the same values as `fft(x[1:N])`. They each represent a different set of frequencies.

Comment: In many cases,  we just return fixed say length 4096 results for any inputs then it is actually O(1) respect inputs?

Comment: @hxd1011: Yes. O(1) means that the computation time is fixed no matter how large the input is. That is the case here. It doesn’t mean it’s cheap or fast, it just means independent of input size.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Can I interest you in a [bounty for a 2D FFT question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61718126/176769)?